# Exercise 8.4(a) of Do Carmo, Riemannian Geometry

Tags: group-theory, riemannian-geometry, isometry

> Identify $\mathbb R^4$ with $\mathbb C^2$ by letting $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ correspond to $(x_1+ix_2,x_3+ix_4)$. Let
>   $$
> S^3 = \{ (z_1,z_2) \in C^2 \mid |z_1|^2+|z_2|^2=1 \},
> $$
>   and let $h : S^3 \to S^3$ be given by 
>   $$
> h(z_1,z_2)=(e^{\frac{2\pi i}q}z_1,e^{\frac{2\pi i r}q}z_2), \quad (z_1,z_2) \in S^3,
> $$
>   where $q$ and $r$ are relatively prime integers and $q > 2$.
>
> (a) Show that $G = \{\text{id},h,\ldots,h^{q-1}\}$ is a group of isometries of the sphere $S^3$, with the usual metric, which operates in a totally discontinuous manner. The manifold $S^3 / G$ is called a *lens space*.
>
> (b) Consider $S^3 / G$ with the metric induced by the projection $p : S^3 \to S^3 / G$. Show that all the geodesics of $S^3 / G$ are closed but can have different lengths.

My question comes from only part (a). I was already able to show that $G$ is a group which operates in a totally discontinuous manner. So my only question is how to show that $h : S^3 \to S^3$ is an isometry.

Intuitively, I can see that it is an isometry because the moduli of both $(z_1,z_2)$ and $h(z_1,z_2)$ are the same.

But I have trouble trying to show this explicitly, with the definition of isometry given by p. 35 of do Carmo:

> Let $M$ and $N$ be Riemannian manifolds. A diffeomorphism $f : M \to N$ is called an *isometry* if
>   $$
> \langle u,v\rangle_p = \langle df_p(u),df_p(v)\rangle_{f(p)}
> $$
>   for all $p \in M$ and $u,v\in T_pM$.

Comment: Use the hermitian inner product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $k \in \{0,\ldots,q-1\}$ and if $u,v \in T_pS^3 \subset \mathbb C^2$ are given by
$$
u=(u_1,u_2)=(u^1_1+iu^2_1,u^1_2+iu^2_2) \quad \text{and} \quad v=(v_1,v_2)=(v^1_1+iv^2_1,v^1_2+iv^2_2)
$$
and we define $\alpha=\frac{2\pi k}q$ and $\beta=\frac{2\pi k r}q$, then 
\begin{align}
(e^{ik\alpha}u_1, e^{ik\beta}u_2) &= ((\cos(k\alpha)+i\sin(k\alpha))(u_1^1+iu_1^2),(\cos(k\beta)+i\sin(k\beta))(u_2^1+iu_2^2)) \\ 
&= (u_1^1 \cos (k\alpha)-u_1^2 \sin(k\alpha))+i(u_1^2 \cos (k\alpha)+u_1^1 \sin(k\alpha)), \\ 
&\qquad \qquad (u_2^1 \cos (k\beta)-u_2^2 \sin(k\beta))+i(u_2^2 \cos (k\beta)+u_2^1 \sin(k\beta))) \\ 
&= (u_1^1 \cos (k\alpha)-u_1^2 \sin(k\alpha),u_1^2 \cos (k\alpha)+u_1^1 \sin(k\alpha),\\ 
&\qquad \qquad u_2^1 \cos (k\beta)-u_2^2 \sin(k\beta),u_2^2 \cos (k\beta)+u_2^1 \sin(k\beta)),
\end{align}
where the last equality was due to associating $\mathbb R^4$ with $\mathbb C^2$.

Similarly,
\begin{align}
(e^{ik\alpha}v_1, e^{ik\beta}v_2) 
&= (v_1^1 \cos (k\alpha)-v_1^2 \sin(k\alpha),v_1^1 \cos (k\alpha)+v_1^1 \sin(k\alpha),\\ 
&\qquad \qquad v_2^1 \cos (k\beta)-v_2^2 \sin(k\beta),v_2^2 \cos (k\beta)+v_2^1 \sin(k\beta)).
\end{align}
Therefore,
\begin{align}
\langle dh^k(u),dh^k(v) \rangle_{h^\ell(p)} &= \langle(e^{ik\alpha}u_1, e^{ik\beta}u_2),(e^{ik\alpha}v_1, e^{ik\beta}v_2)\rangle \\
&= (u_1^1 \cos (k\alpha)-u_1^2 \sin(k\alpha))((v_1^1 \cos (k\alpha)-v_1^2 \sin(k\alpha)) \\ 
&\qquad + (u_1^2 \cos (k\alpha)+u_1^1 \sin(k\alpha))(v_1^2 \cos (k\alpha)+v_1^1 \sin(k\alpha)) \\
&\qquad + (u_2^1 \cos (k\beta)-u_2^2 \sin(k\beta))(v_2^1 \cos (k\beta)-v_2^2 \sin(k\alpha)) \\
&\qquad + (u_2^2 \cos (k\beta)+u_2^1 \sin(k\beta))(v_2^2 \cos (k\beta)+v_2^1 \sin(k\alpha)) \\
&= u_1^1v_1^1 + u_1^2 v_1^2 + u_2^1 v_2^1 + u_2^2 v_2^2 \\
&= \langle (u_1^1,u_1^2,u_2^1,u_2^2),(v_1^1,v_1^2,v_2^1,v_2^2) \rangle \\ 
&= \langle (u_1^1+iu_1^2,u_2^1+iu_2^2),(v_1^1+iv_1^2,v_2^1+iv_2^2) \rangle \\ 
&= \langle (u_1,u_2),(v_1,v_2) \rangle \\ 
&= \langle u,v \rangle
\end{align}
and hence $h^k : S^3 \to S^3$ is an isometry.

Comment: That looks good!

Answer (score 4):

Let $\alpha=\frac{2\pi}{q}$ and $\beta=\frac{2\pi r}{q}$, and so $h^k(z_1,z_2)=\left(e^{ik\alpha}z_1,~e^{ik\beta}z_2\right),$ and in turn $$dh^k_{(z_1,z_2)}=\left(e^{ik\alpha}dz_1,e^{ik\beta}dz_2\right),$$ 
where $dz_i=dx_i + idy_i$.

*One of your mistakes is in the expression of the differential.* In your attempt you didn't apply the same linear operator (differential) to both $u$ and $v$.

Now for any $p\in\mathbf{S}^3$ and $u=(u_1,u_2),v=(v_1,v_2)\in T_p\mathbf{S}^3$, where $u_j=u_{j}^1+iu_{j}^2$ and $v_j=v_{j}^1 + i v_j^2$ for $j\in\{1,2\}$.
Now recall that since we identified $\mathbf{R}^4$ with $\mathbf{C}^2$ that the inner product is the inner product on $\mathbf{R}^4$, not the natural Hermitian inner product on $\mathbf{C}^2$ (so you can't pull out the complex constants $e^{ik\alpha}$; on that note, even if the metric was Hermitian you would have to pull out the conjugate of $e^{ik\beta}$ from the right hand side of the inner product). Keeping this in mind we compute
\begin{align*}
\langle dh^k(u),dh^k(v)\rangle_{h^k(p)} & = \left\langle\left(e^{ik\alpha}u_1,~ e^{ik\beta}u_2\right),\left(e^{ik\alpha}v_1,~ e^{ik\beta}v_2\right)\right\rangle\\
& = \left\langle\left((u_1^1+u_1^2)(\cos(k\alpha) + i\sin(k\alpha)),~(u_2^1+ u_2^2)(\cos(k\beta)+i\sin(k\beta)\right),\right.\\
&\qquad\left.\left((v_1^1+v_1^2)(\cos(k\alpha) + i\sin(k\alpha)),~(v_2^1+ v_2^2)(\cos(k\beta)+i\sin(k\beta)\right)\right\rangle \\
& = (u_1^1+u_1^2)(v_1^1+v_1^2)\cos^2(k\alpha)+(u_2^1+u_2^2)(v_2^1+v_2^2)\cos^2(k\beta) \\
&\qquad + (u_1^1+u_1^2)(v_1^1+v_1^2)\sin^2(k\alpha)+(u_2^1+u_2^2)(v_2^1+v_2^2)\sin^2(k\beta) \\
& = (u_1^1+u_1^2)(v_1^1+v_1^2)+(u_2^1+u_2^2)(v_2^1+v_2^2) \\
& = \langle u,v\rangle.
\end{align*}
So we see that $h^k$ is indeed an isometry. Let me know if anything isn't clear.

Comment: If for example $u_1 = u_1^1 + iu_1^2$ (because $u = (u_1,u_2) \in \mathbb C^2$, so $u_1,u_2 \in \mathbb C$), how are you writing $u_1^2 + u_1^2$, without the $i$?

Comment: This is simply since $(u_1,u_2)\in\mathbf{C}^2$ is simply identified with vector in $\mathbf{R}^4$. We are still using the original inner product from $\mathbf{R}^4$. For example, the induced inner product on $\mathbf{C}$ under the identification with $\mathbf{R}^2$ is given by $\langle u_1 + i u_2, v_1 + iv_2\rangle = u_1 v_1 + u_2 v_2$. There is nothing too deep here, it just comes from the first line of your post regarding the identification of $\mathbf{R}^4$ with $\mathbf{C}^2$.

Comment: If you are wondering how I got from the first to the second line of the equality chain in my post, I simply used Euler's formula to convert the exponential expression to a trigonometric one. My bad if I misunderstood what question you were asking!

Comment: Okay, I understand Euler's formula being used. Now, did we also identify $(\cos (k\alpha)+i \sin (k\alpha),\cos (k\beta)+i \sin (k\beta)) \in \mathbb C^2$ with $(\cos (k\alpha),\sin (k\alpha),\cos (k\beta),\sin (k\beta)) \in \mathbb  R^4$ to achieve the third equality in your work?

Comment: Yes! That is exactly the identification in play

Comment: By the way, I think there is a typo in your second-to-last inequality: you wrote "$(u_1^1+u_1^2)(v_1^1+v_1^2)+(u_2^1+u_2^2)(v_2^1+v_2^2)$" twice.

Answer (score 2):

Another way : We can extend $h$-action on $\mathbb{R}^4$. That is, $h$ can be
viewed as an element in $SO(4)$. Note that $S^3$ is invariant under
$h$. Since $S^3$ has a metric induced from $\mathbb{R}^4$, for $x,\
y\in S^3$, there are curves $c_i$ in $S^3$ from $x$ to $y$ s.t. $$
d_{S^3}(x,y) =\lim_i\ {\rm length}\ c_i $$

And since $h$ is an isometry, $$ d_{S^3} (h(x),h(y)) \leq \lim_i\
{\rm length}\ h\circ c_i =d_{S^3}(x,y) \ \ast$$

If $c$ is a curve in $S^3$ from $h(x)$ to $h(y)$ s.t. ${\rm length}\
c< d_{S^3}(x,y) $, then $h^{-1}\circ c$ is a curve from $x$ to $y$.

Hence there is no such curve $c$ so that an inequality in $\ast$ is
an equality.